Craft CMS 5 Headless live preview using nuxt not working
I'm not understanding how the preview mode exactly works trough graphql queries for Craft CMS headless. Using Craft CMS 5.
From what I read, all I have to do is add the 'token' in the headers of the GraphQL call and Craft CMS will return the correct information.
I tried adding the token I get from the preview in the graphql editor and see if it returns the text changed during preview but it only shows the published version.
If I add "drafts: true" in the request I get the latest draft.
Any advice?
Thanks in advance!
